# Running Complex Command with SUDO

Tags: bash, sudo, pipe, command

I need to run the following command with `sudo` (technically just the `dd` part of this command needs `sudo`):

```
xz -d -c -v nvme0n1.dd.xz | xdelta3 -e -9 < (dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=1GB) nvme0n1.dd.xdelta
```

Usually when I need to run something like this with multiple pipes as `sudo` I simply pass it as a string to:

```
sudo bash -c "command"
```

But when I do that with this command I get the following error:

```
bash: Syntax error near unexpected token (
```

I tried escaping the brackets but when I do that I get:

```
bash: (dd no such file or directory
```

What's the best approach to run this command as `sudo`?

Comment: I don't think you can have whitespace between the `<` and `(` in a bash process substitution - regardless of the use of `sudo`

Comment: What steeldriver just said. Also, I notice that your error messages have `Bash` capitalized rather than `bash`. This tells me you have modified the error messages. Please don't do that. We need to trust that what you show is exactly what you see.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by steeldriver the issue was indeed the extra space between < and (.